# Applying style to span and table not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to apply CSS styles to page elements that are dynamically inserted in a page, but my approach isn't working.  Using code similar to what I've inserted below, I notice that when I inspect element in chrome, the  and  tags surround the table content, but the  and  tags *both* precede the table row/table data content - e.g., the inspect element view looks like...

```
<span>
     <table></table>
       <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
       </tr>
<span>
```

Any idea why the closing table tag isn't appearing after the table row/data tags?  Also, why isn't the background-color style being applied?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Simplified code snippets:

```
<script>


     function insertComments(topic_id){
            $.getJSON("getComments.py", {topic_id:topic_id, user_id:user_id}, function(data){
                 $('#tcomment_'+ topic_id).empty();
                 $('#tcomment_'+ topic_id).html('<table>');
                 for (i in data){
                   var commenter_profile_picture = data[i]["profile_picture"];
                   var commenter_name = data[i]["commenter_name"];
                   var commenter_person_id = data[i]["commenter_person_id"];
                   var comment = data[i]["comment"];
                   $('#tcomment_'+ topic_id).append('<tr><td><img src="'+commenter_profile_picture+'" height="20" width="20"></td><td>&nbsp;<a href="person.html?pID='+commenter_person_id+'">'+ commenter_name+'</a> - <span class="comment">'+comment+'</span></td></tr>');
                 }
                 $('#tcomment_'+ topic_id).append('</table>');
            });
     }

     function insertCommentContainer(topic_id){
           $("#comments").append('<span id="tcomment_'+topic_id+'" style="background-color:lightcyan;"></span>');
     }

    var topic_id = 124
    var user_id = 3

    insertCommentContainer(topic_id);
    insertComments(topic_id);

</script>

<html>
    <body>
        <div id="comments">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, what a mess...Plus I get a bunch of errors in jslint with your code. You may want to take a look

Comment: `<table>` is not a valid child of `<span>`. You should be using a `<div>` as your comment container.

Comment: @Brandan - Thanks!  Your suggestion combined with Jim Garrison's fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#tcomment_'+ topic_id).html('<table>');
```

Completely replaces the HTML of the referenced element with a complete `<table>` element.  It generated the closing `</table>` for you.  Then

```
$('#tcomment_'+ topic_id).append('<tr><td><img src="...
```

appended its argument AFTER the last element in the DOM tree fragment already in the referenced element.  This is why your table row appeared after the table.

You should build the HTML in a variable first, and then use `$(...).html( )` to set the HTML all at once.

Comment: Thanks!  Combining your suggestion with @ Brandan's to use a <div> as the comment container did the trick.  Interestingly, $(...).html(html_to_insert) didn't work when I included the table tags in the "html_to_insert" variable - e.g. if the variable value starts with <table> and ends with </table>.  To get it to work, I had to use: $(...).html('<table>' + html_to_insert + '</table>') and remove the table tags from "html_to_insert".

Answer (score 0):

Well, really don't know where to start. Don't know what's causing your problems since the code is so unreadable but:

**1)** `user_id` was used before it was defined

```
{topic_id: topic_id, user_id: user_id // Not declared }
```

**2)** You should probably close your table, not necessary but better

```
$('#tcomment_'+ topic_id).html('<table>'); // Nop
$('#tcomment_'+ topic_id).html('<table><table/>');
```

**3)** `i` needs to be defined:

```
for (i in data){} // Nop
for (var i in data){}
```

**4)** Missing `;`

```
// Nop
var topic_id = 124
var user_id = 3

// Yup
var topic_id = 124,
    user_id = 3; // This is being declared too late
```

**5)** No need for this if you properly create your html:

```
$('#tcomment_' + topic_id).append('</table>');
```

**6)** `<span>` is an `inline` element which can't have `block` elements such as `<table>`.

**7)** You're mixing single quotes and double quotes. Choose one.

Again, I don't know what's wrong but it seems a lot of things are.

Answer (score 0):

your TR and TD are not inside the table

```
<span>
 <table><!-- Table rows and data should come here --></table>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
<span>
```